# Jumping in 2D vectors

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, memory-address

I'm getting crazy with 2D vectors!

After hours of tries I finally figured out how to initialize one of them: `num.resize(3, std::vector<unsigned short>(9));`

Now there's a problem... With this initialization method I create three separate vectors and **then** I put them togheter, so I cannot do something like this:
`*(&val - 9)`
where *val* is
`unsigned short& val = num[1][1];`
if I want to jump to *num[0][1]*.

In a 2D array it works beacuse I jump backwards by 9 addresses, but now it obviously doesn't work because *num[1]* is not consecutive to *num[0]*

Is there any way to initialize my 2D vector making it like a 2D array, or any way of using *val* for jumping backwards by 9 addresses?

I hope I have been clear and... Sorry for my bad english ;)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this cross-row jumping causes undefined behavior (even if it usually works) even for plain 2D arrays.

Comment: This can help.. https://thispointer.com/creating-a-matrix-using-2d-vector-in-c-vector-of-vectors/

Comment: I suggest using a 1D vector of size `W*H`, possibly wrapped in some matrix class.